# 3rd Party Library throws NoClassDefFoundError without giving a class name

Tags: debugging, java1.4

I'm trying to integrate a 3rd party library into an existing application; it compiles and builds with no problems, but during execution gives a `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`.

The problem is that the error comes out of the library to which I don't have the source, and the error doesn't tell me what class couldn't be found.

Is it possible to debug this?  Any advice?

(It's a Java 1.4, Eclipse, Ant and Tomcat set-up)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install [JD-Eclipse](http://java.decompiler.free.fr/?q=jdeclipse) (or any other decompiler), fire up your debugger, and step through until you find the error.

The plugin should allow you to step into the third party .class files as if they were attached source (assuming they're not obfuscated).

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that - it'll have to wait until after the weekend though.